Does Xと同じ and Xも同じ mean the same thing?
It seems to me that there is no difference in meaning between Xと同じ and Xも同じ. They both translate to "same as X" is that right? Are there any situations when Xも同じ is understood as "X is also same"? For example あなたも同じ危険な立場なんだ can either mean "(someone) is in the same dangerous position as you" or "you are also in the same dangerous position"?

The full sentence of your example would be like:

あなたもXXと同じ危険な立場なんだ

あなた, marked with も here, is the subject of the sentence, while XX, marked with と, is the target of the comparison. So it would mean "You are also in the same dangerous position (as somebody)."
The basic structure is:

「A は/が B と同じだ」 "A is the same as B"
「A も B と同じだ」 "A is (also) the same as B"

Compare:
「あなたと同じ」 "(someone is) the same as you"
「あなたも同じ」 "you are (also) the same (as somebody)"

By the way, 「～も同じ」 has another usage: it can be used in the meaning of 「～も同然」, e.g. 「死んだも同じ」"as good as dead; might as well be dead" ≈「死んだも同然」, 「殺したも同じだ」≈「殺したも同然だ」
